# Disable button after submit PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this code that when submitted, it generates random number from the array.

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['roll'])) {
        $randarray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
        $randselect = array_rand($randarray);
        $nr = $randarray[$randselect];
        echo '<p class="btn btn-info"> Branch: '. $nr. '</p>'; 
    }

?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="roll">Roll Branch </button> 
</form>
```

What I wanted to do is after the form was submitted, the button will be disabled. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `disabled` if the button is pressed, e.g.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="roll" <?php echo isset($_POST["roll"]) ? "disabled" : "";?>>Roll Branch </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="roll" <?php echo isset($_POST['roll']) ? 'disabled="true"' : ''; ?> >Roll Branch </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `onclick="this.disabled='true';"` for button tag

Comment: It will not echo out the random number.

Comment: Why? I suggest to extend your answer with a little bit of explanation, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not getting enabled after page post and I got some error.
In my situation my signup page have a submit button. Below is the code :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="signup-form" name="signup-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="txtFormNo" name="txtFormNo" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Form No" required readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-4">
      <label for="standard">Select Standard</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="standard" name="standard" required>
        <option>FYJC</option>
        <option>SYJC</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtSeatNo">SSC Seat No</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="txtSeatNo" name="txtSeatNo" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="SSC Seat No" maxlength="7" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmSeatNo">Re-enter SSC Seat No</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmSeatNo" name="confirmSeatNo" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Re-enter SSC Seat No" maxlength="7" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php if (isset($_GET['flag']) != 'newsyjc') { ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtSscAppNo">Enter Unique Application ID</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="UNIQUE APPLICATION ID" autocomplete="off" name="txtSscAppNo" id="txtSscAppNo" maxlength="6" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="confirmSscAppNo">Re-enter Unique Application ID</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Re-enter UNIQUE APPLICATION ID" autocomplete="off" name="confirmSscAppNo" id="confirmSscAppNo" maxlength="6" required />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtContact">Enter Contact No.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="txtContact" name="txtContact" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Contact" maxlength="10" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmContact">Re-enter Contact No.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmContact" name="confirmContact" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-enter Contact" maxlength="10" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtEmail">Enter Email ID</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email ID" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmEmail">Re-enter Email ID</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-enter Email ID" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="d-inline-block mr-3">
        <label class="control control-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" required />
          <div class="control-indicator"></div>
          I Agree the terms and conditions
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mb-4" name = "btnSignup" id = "btnSignup" 
      <?php echo isset($_POST["btnSignup"]) ? "disabled" : "";?> >Sign Up</button>
      <p>Already have an account?
        <a class="text-blue" href="login.php">Sign in</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP Code :

```
if (isset($_POST['btnSignup'])) {

    $standard = trim($_POST['standard']);
    $SeatNo = trim($_POST['txtSeatNo']);
    $cSeatNo = trim($_POST['confirmSeatNo']);
    $FormNo = trim($_POST['txtFormNo']);
    $contact = trim($_POST['txtContact']);
    $cContact = trim($_POST['confirmContact']);
    $Email = trim($_POST['txtEmail']);
    $cEmail = trim($_POST['confirmEmail']);
    $code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM stud_personal_details WHERE SeatNo=:SeatNo");
    $stmt->execute(array(":SeatNo"=>$SeatNo));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($flag == 'newsyjc') {

        $SscAppNo = '';
        $cSscAppNo = '';

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-error'>
                        <strong>Sorry !</strong> Seat No is Already Registered.<br>
                        Please enter your correct Seat No OR <a class='btn btn-success btn-lg' href='login.php'>Click here to login !</a>
                    </div>";
        } else if ($standard == 'SYJC') {
            if ($user->stud_personal_details($SeatNo, $FormNo, $SscAppNo, $Password, $contact, $code, $Email) && 
                $user->stud_admission_details($SeatNo, $SscAppNo) &&
                $user->stu_app($SeatNo, $code) && 
                $user->Marks($SeatNo) ) {

                    $user->send_sms($SeatNo, $Password, $Email);

                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
                                <strong>Success!</strong>  Your account is created.<br>
                                Password have been SMS on ".$contact." and mailed at ".$Email."<br>
                                <p><a class='text-blue' href='login.php'>Click here to login !</a></p>
                            </div>";
                    //header("refresh:3;login.php?flag=".$flag);
                } else {
                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                                <strong>Sorry !</strong> Something went wrong.<br>
                                Contact college office or IT Charge of College.
                            </div>";
                }
        }
    } else if ($days > 0) {

        $SscAppNo = trim($_POST['txtSscAppNo']);
        $cSscAppNo = trim($_POST['confirmSscAppNo']);

        if (strlen($SeatNo) != 7 ) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> SSC Seat Number is a 7 alpha-numberic combination.<br>
                        Please enter again.
                    </div>";
        } else if ($cSeatNo !== $SeatNo) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> <strong>Sorry!</strong> SSC Seat Number doesn't match.<br>
                        Please enter again.
                    </div>";
        } else if (strlen($SscAppNo) != 6 ) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> UNIQUE APPLICATION ID should be 6 numberic value.<br>
                        Please enter again.
                    </div>";
        } else if ($cSscAppNo !== $SscAppNo) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> <strong>Sorry!</strong> UNIQUE APPLICATION ID doesn't match.<br>
                        Please enter again.
                    </div>";
        } else if (strlen($contact) != 10 ) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> Contact No. should be of 10 digits.
                    </div>";
        } else if ($contact!==$cContact) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> <strong>Sorry!</strong> Contact No. Doesn't match.
                    </div>";
        } else if ($cEmail!==$Email) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> <strong>Sorry!</strong> Email Doesn't match.<br>
                        Please enter again.
                    </div>";
        } else if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                        <i class='mdi mdi-alert mr-1'></i> <strong>Sorry !</strong> Seat No is Already Registered.<br>
                        Please enter your correct Seat No OR <a class='btn btn-success btn-lg' href='login.php?days=".$days."'>Click here to login !</a>
                    </div>";
        } else if ($standard == 'FYJC') {
            if ($user->stud_personal_details($SeatNo, $FormNo, $SscAppNo, $Password, $contact, $code, $Email) && 
                $user->stud_admission_details($SeatNo, $SscAppNo) &&
                $user->stu_app($SeatNo, $code) && 
                $user->Marks($SeatNo) ) {

                    $user->send_sms($SeatNo, $Password, $Email, $contact);

                    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
                                <strong>Success!</strong>  Your account is created.<br>
                                Password have been send on ".$contact." and also mailed at ".$Email."<br>
                                <a class='btn btn-success btn-lg' href='login.php?days=".$days."'>Click here to login !</a>
                            </div>";
            } else {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                            <strong>Sorry !</strong> Something went wrong...<br>
                            Contact college office or IT Charge of College.
                        </div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It stays disabled incase of some error or otherwise even after success. I mean to say it should stay disable when clicked but should get enable as soon as some error or success occurs so that user can again fill the form and click on submit again.