# Disable button on submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zurb-foundation

Hello so I am using foundation data-abide for input validation in my form and here is my code. In my index.php here is the code

```
<a href="upload-photo.php" data-reveal-id="uploadModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">Add Photo</a>
 <div id="uploadModal" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal></div>
```

Whenever I click on add photo, the upload-photo.php shows up in a modal. In the modal it contains this code

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-abide name="formupload" id="uploadID">
<div class="photo-field">
<input type="file" name="file_img" pattern="^.+?\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|gif|png|PNG)$" required>
<small class="error">Upload JPG or PNG only.</small>
</div>
<div class="title-field">
<input type="text" name="img_title" placeholder="Image title" required>
<small class="error">Image title is required.</small>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="btn_upload" class="button">
</form>
```

If I ever want to use a script like this and click the submit button, it doesn't work. It just shows the upload-photo.php again in a page, not in a modal.

```
$('form#uploadID').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

What is the possible way to submit the form and then disables the button so no one can spam clicking it? Thanks!

Comment: What is different to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30284668 ?

Comment: Simply give id to that submit button and disable that button

Comment: What means `it doesn't work` ? You have to note that a submit will trigger a page-reload. Therefore the disabled button will be enabled again

Comment: @Rizier123 you might want to check my update.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia did it and the problem is written there

Comment: @empiric check my post again please thanks

Comment: you should be using a serverside solution with sessions and tokens also as a "Plan B"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#uploadID').submit(function(){
    $('#uploadID input[name=btn_upload]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```