# Getting the condition of if isset submit button using PHP

Tags: php, html, submit, isset

I have a html code and php code that will execute a program when the I hit the submit button. I'm trying execute my code while the Submit button is disabled. The button disabled but it did not execute my php code. Is there a condition for if(isset) when the button is disabled? Can you give me tips on this?

Here's my **html code:**

```
  <form method ="POST">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GENERATE report" onclick="this.disabled=true;"> <br />
```

Here's my **php code**

```
<?php


     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

       echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("disabled")';
                    echo '</script>';

     }

?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `ob_start()` but don't get buffer contents?

Comment: sorry, accidentally copied that when editting... to be honest, its a really long code... however, I'm just focusing on the button control first for the user

Comment: You need to disable the button after submitting the form

Comment: I would think you would assign an event handler to the form `onsubmit` that disables the button because as soon as you disable the button ( as you are ) the default action of the button will be cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the button after submitting the form.

or use condition to disable the button.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GENERATE report" <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> > <br />
```

Comment: I was browsing google for a similar question of mine and I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284668/disable-button-after-submit-php 
I did the code and it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to go through the link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_submit_disabled.asp

the submit button is valid only if its not disabled.

The onclick function you specified disables your submit button and since it only submits after executing the onclick, after the onclick the button is no longer valid and hence the form will not be submitted.

due to this the request will not be sent to the server and the PHP code you wrote will not be executed at all.

whatever your intention might be, I suggest you call a function on onclick and in that function, disable the submit button and then alert that the button is disabled. your current method will not work.